# How to correctly set optimization.splitChunks.automaticNameDelimiter value using Webpack chain syntax?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, config, vuejs3

I'm looking to modify the [splitChunks.automaticNameDelimiter](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunksautomaticnamedelimiter) Webpack setting when using Vue CLI `vue.config.js` settings, but I don't quite understand the required syntax.

This default delimiter character is a `~` and this is causing problems with the environment I am trying to upload my application to. I want to use `-` delimiters instead.

The Vue CLI docs for [Modifying Options of a Plugin](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-plugin)  suggest that I should be doing something like this:

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  publicPath: '/app/',
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('optimization')
      .options('splitChunks', { automaticNameDelimiter: '-' })
  }
}
```

This above is not correct, but don't understand from the [webpack-chain docs](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain#getting-started) what I should be doing instead to modify the `optimization.splitChunks.automaticNameDelimiter` with the chaining syntax?

Please help! Many thanks in advance.

It will not take the settings like in the same way as `webpack.config.js`, which is apparently invalid:

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  publicPath: '/app/',
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      automaticNameDelimiter: '-'
    }
  }
}
```

Currently using package versions `webpack` 4.45.0 and `webpack-chain` 6.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. [more info](https://github.com/neutrinojs/webpack-chain/tree/v5#configuring-optimizations-shorthand-methods)

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  publicPath: '/app/',
  chainWebpack: config => {
        config.optimization.splitChunks({
            ...config.optimization.get('splitChunks'),
            automaticNameDelimiter: '-'
        })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you muchly 

Answer (score 1):

Webpack Chain module also exposes the `merge(...)` method on chained maps like `config.optimization`. You could use this as an alternative and less verbose syntax:

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false,
  publicPath: '/app/',
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.optimization.merge({
      splitChunks: { 
        automaticNameDelimiter: '-'
      }
    });
  },
};
```